# ¿Cómo hacer un algoritmo de encuesta con valores aleatorios? En java

Tags: java

Queremos realizar una encuesta a 10 personas, en la que se indicará el género (1=femenino, 2=masculino, 3=otro), si trabaja (1=si trabaja, 2= no trabaja) y su remuneracion (solo si tiene un trabajo, de no tenerlo, le debes asignar cero), que irá entre 300 y 2500 (valor entero y expresado en miles de pesos).

Los valores deben ser generados aleatoriamente.

Para generar números aleatorios, en PSeint, se utiliza la siguiente instrucción:

valor <- azar(valormayor)

Donde valormayor, corresponde al número mayor que puede asumir, y valor corresponde a la variable donde quedará.

En Java, se utiliza lo siguiente:

valor = (int) (Math.random() * valormayor);

Donde, valor y valormayor tienen los mismos objetivos descritos en Pseint, el (int) hace una conversión del tipo de dato (de double a entero).

Calcula y muestra lo siguiente:

De la muestra total, el porcentaje de hombres, porcentaje de mujeres y porcentaje de otros géneros.
De cada subgrupo (hombres, mujeres y otros), el porcentaje de trabaja.
Sueldo promedio de los hombres que trabajan, de mujeres y de otros que trabajan.Ja

Comment: Hola inesisarabbit, bienvenida, tu pregunta se parece mucho a "tengo este ejercicio, resuélvanlo", este tipo de preguntas, no suelen ser bien recibidas, te sugiero que la edites, y muestres que has intentado, para saber que formas parte de la resolución de tu problema, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obten

Comment: Cuál es la pregunta?

Answer (score -1):

Desde la version Java 1.7, puedes usar la clase java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom y especificamente el metodo nextInt(a,b) donde a, es el limite inferior, y b el limite superior. Por ejemplo podrias usar este snippet de codigo

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

int genero = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1,3);
int trabajo = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1,2);
int pago = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(300,1200);
```

Como referencia, hay mas informacion de esta clase en la [documentacion de Oracle aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextInt(int,int)).

Una vez se vayan generando los numeros la mejor opcion me pareceria ir agregandolos a un [arreglo](https://www.manualweb.net/java/arrays-java/) y luego contar las ocurrencias de cada valor en el arreglo para ir sacando los porcentajes despues dividiendo el nunmero de ocurrencias por el tamano total del arreglo, [en esta pagina hay varios ejemplos](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-number-of-occurrences-or-frequency-in-a-sorted-array/) para contar ocurrencias en arreglos con distintos metodos y lenguajes incluyendo Java